# How do I get checkboxes to work with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I'm having trouble getting my checkbox to work for my homework assignment.  I know it has something to do with a unique key after I'm iterating through my object via jsx, but no matter what combinations I try, the checkbox doesn't work.

Object Code

```
export const initialTodoState = [{

    item:"Learn about reducers",
    complete: false,
    id: Date.now()

},

{

    item: "Learn Redux",
    complete: false,
    id: Date.now()
},

{

    item: "Learn UX design",
    complete: false,
    id: Date.now()
}
];
```

Ul code

```
         <ul>
             {filteredTodos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={cuid()}>
            <label>
              <input
              type="checkbox"
                checked={todo.complete}
                onChange={() => handleChanges(todo)}
              />
              {todo.item}
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

handleChanges code

```
const handleChanges = todo => {
        dispatch({
          type: todo.complete ? 'UNDO_TODO' :'DO_TODO'  ,
          id: todo.id
        });
      };
```

Comment: Can you add a Codesandbox link for a preview?

Comment: share reducer please

Comment: Live: https://codesandbox.io/live/GK9nK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pass `todo.id` as key. Your element key should not change over render. I recommend you to read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) more carefully.